# .git folder with almost 30GB

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have this issue in a server where the .git folder takes almost 30GB. Is there any command (bitbucket) to clean data from a specific date? I don't want to add more disk space in there.

Comment: Are you checking in binary (compiled?) files? This adds to the size of the git repo drastically with every checkin. Generally, you should keep your binaries out of source control, for example by adding them to your .gitignore

Comment: More generally, don't commit anything that can be generated from something in the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick workaround would be to use shallow clone with `git clone --depth=5`. This will reduce the history of the cloned repo:

> --depth <depth>
>
> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. Implies `--single-branch` unless `--no-single-branch` is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches. If you want to clone submodules shallowly, also pass `--shallow-submodules`.

You should however identify what's taking up the whole 30GB.

Start by [finding large objects](https://github.com/kdowbecki/dotfiles/blob/master/git/git-large-objects) in the repository. If you see something that was incorrectly committed and can be removed, e.g. large binary files that were committed by mistake, you can delete these with [the BFG tool](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/removing-large-files-git-bfg).